# How to override a property defined in profile-specific application-{profile}.yml for a single application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a `spring-cloud-config` server set up to serve YML files from a git repository. The server is using Spring Cloud `2020.0.3`. There are several `spring-cloud-config` clients consuming config files from the server. The client applications consuming the config are using Spring Boot 2.4.6 and the new config parsing implementation.

The config repository contains an `application-db.yml` file and `myapp.yml` file. The `application-db.yml` file has several common properties set that all applications will use for the `db` profile. `myapp.yml` has properties for a specific application. Prior to using Spring Boot 2.4.6, I was able to override properties from `application-db.yml` in `myapp.yml`. In effect, the `application-db.yml` properties were the default values that individual applications could override.

For example `application-db.yml` might have (property key is not relevant):

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 5
```

to set the connection pool size to `5` for most applications and `myapp.yml` could set

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
```

for a one-off connection pool size of `10`.

In Spring Cloud `2020.0.3` (Spring Cloud Config `3.0.4`) and Spring Boot `2.4.6`, the behavior is that the property in `application-db.yml` cannot be overridden in `myapp.yml` and the connection pool size property always has value `5`.

I have tried setting the following properties in the `application.yml` and still have the same results.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      allowOverride: true
      overrideNone: true
      overrideSystemProperties: false
```

According to [Config file processing in Spring Boot 2.4](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) overriding property values is allowed in the config processing, but it is dependent on document order.

Is the overriding behavior still supported by Spring Boot using Spring Cloud Config? If so, does it depend on the order the cloud config server serves the documents? Is there a way to control the order?

edit note: I originally posted about overriding properties in the `application.yml` file. After more investigation, that does allowing overriding. It is in the profile specific files like `application-db.yml` that I cannot override values. I'm starting to think this might be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The overriding behavior you are looking for is supported in the latest release documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_client_side_usage) and should be the default behavior without needing to add additional properties to enable override. You will need to include the application name with the spring.application.name property for the config server to recognize the overriding file.The overriding file also needs to have the same name you give in the client application (in this case,for example, my config repo has files application.properties and myapp.properties.

**Client application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=myapp
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
...
```

**Server application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=configserver
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/...
server.port=8888
...
```

**Within config repo**

**application.properties**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 5
```

**myapp.properties**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
```

If the client application cannot fetch the overriding file (in this case the myapp file) from the config server application, it will fall back to its local application.properties file. However, the application will probably fail if all of the properties your application needs are not present there as well, so it's a good practice to copy all properties from your overriding file to the client application.properties file in case fetch fails.

If this didn't fix your problem I would check out [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#property-overrides) section on property overrides.

Comment: thanks for providing the detailed explanation, after more investigation I found the issue only affects profile specific config files. I edited my question to be more accurate